# Stop VM in GCP and wait till it is stopped using gcp python sdk

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, sdk, google-api-client

I want to stop the VM in gcp and wait till the process is complete.
Right now if I hit

```
request = service.instances().stop(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance_name)
```

it exits without waiting till the VM is actually in stopped state.

Comment: You have to loop and request the VM state to wait, by yourselves the effective stop. But why waiting for this?

Comment: Yep. Had to build my logic to check the stop state of node.

Answer (score 0):

I had to build my own logic to check the terminate state of the list of vms.

```
vm_status = {}
operation_status = {}
for instance_name, instance_details in instances.items():
    print("Switching {} VM {}".format(state, instance_name))
    if state == 'OFF':
        request = service.instances().stop(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance_name)
    elif state == 'ON':
        request = service.instances().start(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance_name)
    response = request.execute()
    operation_status[response['name']] = response['status']
    print(response)

    vm_status[instance_name] = response['status']
print("Waiting till all the VMs are in {}".format(state))
print(vm_status)
wait_for_operation(service, )
timeout = time.time() + 60 * 15

if state == 'OFF':
    all_stop = False
    while (not all_stop or time.time() > timeout):

        for instance_name, instance_details in instances.items():
            request = service.instances().get(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance_name)
            response = request.execute()
            vm_status[instance_name] = response['status']
        stop = True
        for instance_name, status in vm_status.items():
            if status != 'TERMINATED':
                stop = False
                break
        print(vm_status)
        if stop:
            all_stop = True
        time.sleep(1)
```